# Datatel/colleage data exchange

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server

I am looking for information on exchanging data with colleague.  Use cases include pulling data from an applicant/student record, and notifying colleague of certain events.  Information on uniObjects, ELF, and EDX preferably with a .Net flavor would all be appreciated.   Looking for the most efficient way to get this done.

Comment: So your question boils down to essentially "how do I exchange data"?

Comment: @Matti: Of course, could it be any simpler? :)

Comment: Ever get anywhere on this?  I'm looking for similar information.  It looks like they released a .NET SDK recently.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.figsolutions.com/tmi

We use this for KPI reporting and document management (updating comm codes via XML calls) as well as real time relational data warehouse transfers from unidata to mysql/mssql/oracle.

It's works by placing unidata triggers on records that fire the listener, which then creates a SQL script to send to the warehouse db server. Communicates in both directions too.

Works really well with Unidata. You can even fire off Unidata SUBRs via XML calls and get the result back in XML.